# Microsoft Excel 2016 copy paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have problem in copying from excel to word, i have tables in excel that i want to copy to excel. 
Prob 1:
when i copy them as bulk. it's really pain in the ass to give the explanation in the word.

[image]

Prob 2:
if i copy them one by one, the columns width are keep changing altough in the excel they are the same width.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So do a sized screen shot of the table as you want it (cmnd-shift-4 if you are on a mac) then paste it as an image.

Comment: It's best to ask a single question if the two questions are not directly connected to one another.  Your question is a little confusing if your asking about Excel but have provided screenshots of tables within Word.